Heroku WebSocket message size
I am hosting server on Heroku. Two machines are connected to it and I would like to send images between them. I am using WebSockets for this. It works when I host it locally but not when it is hosted on Heroku. How can I check/improve WebSocket message size or what are the alternatives?
I tried splitting image into multiple chunks and it works but it is to slow.
